# User can not insert into datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to use a three-column datagrid so that the user can enter the data into it and then store the data from the datagrid into the database.

But my problem is that I created DataGrid but I can't enter any data.

```
<DataGrid VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
          IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=chkitems, Path=IsChecked}"  
          Height="266" x:Name="dgvitems" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" 
          CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
          CanUserSortColumns="False" IsReadOnly="False" Width="451">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="نام کالا" Width="250" FontSize="14" Binding="{Binding name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="تعداد" Width="80" FontSize="14" Binding="{Binding number}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header=" ">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button x:Name="btndelete"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Click="Btndelete_Click" ToolTip="حذف رکورد" Background="{x:Null}">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="CloseCircle" Foreground="Red" Width="16" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

WPF not Support Direct Binding to DataColumns  first Learn MVVM Architecture And Used MVVM 
pattern ,used ObservableCollection  then enter data Datagrid Columns Accept Automatically